# Open case insensitive connection with IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries ADO.NET provider

Tags: db2, ado.net, ibm-midrange

With ODBC driver, it's possible to set the property `SORTWEIGHT=0` to have case insensitive connexion.
But with IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries ADO.NET provider, I got a error.

Code :

```cs
using (var connection = new iDB2Connection("Data Source=TestDb;User Id=Ali;Password=baba;Naming=system;SORTWEIGHT=0"))
{
    connection.Open();
}
```

Result :

```
IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2InvalidConnectionStringException : 'The ConnectionString property is invalid.'
MessageDetails: "SORTWEIGHT"
```

How can I open a connexion in case insensitive mode with IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries?

Comment: What IBM i version are you connecting to? That option wasn't supported until 7.1 I believe. Also I think each key-value pair in the connection string must be terminated with a semicolon, so try `"Data Source=TestDb;User Id=Ali;Password=baba;Naming=system;SORTWEIGHT=0;"`

Comment: I use the DLL IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries version 12. After added a semicolon, I have the same error.

Comment: I'm asking about the server version, not the client.

Comment: The server version is `V7R3M0`

Comment: Try adding SORTTYPE - I found this example SORTTYPE=2;SORTWEIGHT=1; saying SORTWEIGHT is only used if SORTTYPE is 2.  Maybe the ODBC driver does that for you.

Comment: I don't use the ODBC driver, but ADO.NET driver.

Comment: AFAIK you can only make a table that has sort like this.  Anything else will pull all data and then sort it.